# Obtain updated information from other sites and post on your site in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications

Good Day all,

I have an existing site built. I was wondering, how can my site update automatically when another website updates too? This essentially means that my existing site will obtain information like Cost, Description, images from the other site upon update.

I was pondering web services but the other site doesn't have it.

Please advise!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you can't change anything on *the other* site, just on yours?

Comment: does the other site have an API of any kind?

Comment: @deceze - Yup cant change anything

Comment: @Austin L. - No api or whatsoever... hmmmm... am i supposed to build something to steal info? Doesnt sound right...

Comment: Its pretty tricky to pull information from another site without any kind of API. You could explore building some type of script that will phrase the other site's HTML and pull certain information out. The success of that however depends a lot on how well coded the other site is and how specific their HTML tags are.

Comment: I thought you just elegantly danced around the topic of stealing info up until now. Now that you mention it... good luck figuring out by yourself how to steal another developers efforts. :)

Comment: Heh thanks Austin! I was considering that too...but due to the limitation as mentioned by you, might be an issue. However, still worth a try heh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other site doesn't have an API, your only option is page scraping, i.e. downloading the HTML and parsing it to extract the info you want.

If they have a page structure that doesn't change often, this is generally reliable.

You'd probably want to use PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to extract the info.

Generally, people don't like it because badly designed tools can tax their system resources, since generating a whole HTML page is more resource intensive than generating an API response.

Page scraping is fairly widespread, though some people discourage it. It may be disallowed by the TOU of a site, possibly having legal implications.  Or, your target site may have no problem with it. There are of course large businesses built on page scraping (see 'Google').

Comment: Hrm... I guess Google *would* be considered a page-scraper. Never thought about it like that before. I think I'd be more concerned about people stealing my content than taxing my server though.